# Docker created files not being saved into volume

Tags: docker

My application generate logs, and I'm trying to save them on a volume. However, when a generated log file is created and writen it is not being saved into the volume.

[Docker Desktop file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piJCs.png)

I can see that the generated log file and volume are not in sync.
Here is the commands I ran:

```
docker volume create be.identity.volume
```

```
docker run -d --name be.identity.container -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 -v be.identity.volume:/app/Logging be.identity
```

I was expecting that when logs are generated it they would automatically be saved into the volume. I also tried with file mounts with this command but same situation happened:

```
docker run -d --name be.identity.container -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 -v C:/Users/myuser/source/repos/Project/_docker/volumes/BE.Identity:/app/Logging be.identity
```

I noticed that putting files into the host path would add them to the docker container, but the generated log files in the container would not be added to the host path.
Do I have any misconception on how are file mounts and volumes supposed to work? How can I persist the generated log files and other types of data generated by the application?

I'm running an asp.net application that generate logs into the folder /app/Logging using serilog library. I would expect that the generated files would be available in the volume, but using docker desktop I can see when I access the volume data a message "No data to display"

Inspecting the container I found this information:

```
"Mounts": [
{
    "Type": "volume",
    "Name": "be.identity.volume",
    "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/be.identity.volume/_data",
    "Destination": "/app/Logging",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Mode": "z",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": ""
}
```

],
"Volumes": null,

Also ran this commands to the container:

> $ pwd
>
> /app/Logging
>
> $ touch example.txt
>
> touch: cannot touch 'example.txt': Permission denied
>
> $ sudo touch example.txt
>
> sh: 10: sudo: not found
>
> $ chmod o+w /app/Logging
>
> chmod: changing permissions of '/app/Logging': Operation not permitted
>
> $ touch example.txt
>
> touch: cannot touch 'example.txt': Permission denied

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including a command that will write logs to a volume that others can reproduce, and the commands you are using to inspect that volume.

Comment: @BMitch I added a paragraph explaining how the application generate the logs and how I see that the volume is empty. But reflecting on your comment, would it be expected to have an additional cammand that makes the copy from the docker filesystem to the volume?

Comment: What code is writing into the `/app/Logging` directory?  What leads you to believe the volume is empty?  You can't normally see the contents of a named volume from the host, especially if you're using Docker Desktop or another VM-based solution.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, I figured out the problem, but I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out I was using the wrong path to generate logs. I'm running on a windows computer so I had configurated the path `Logging\\Logs.txt`. Since docker on windows uses WSL I had to change it to `Logging/Logs.txt`